# How to access each field of wagtail FreeForm in HTML pages?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have created wagtail FreeForm by extending `WagtailFormBlock` given below.I can create different form using `wagtail admin interface`.

File name: `blocks.py`

```
from wagtailformblocks.blocks import WagtailFormBlock

class MyForm(WagtailFormBlock):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'demo'
```

This is the `models.py` file in which I have created page and assigned form to this page.

File name: `models.py`

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtailformblocks.models import BaseForm
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import StreamField


class FormType(BaseForm):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Form Type"

class ImagePage(Page):
    template = 'wagtail_demo/image_page.html'

    content = StreamField([
        ('my_forms', MyForm()),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('content'),
    ]
```

This is my `image_page.html` page where I want to render the form fields.

File name: `image_page.html`

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
{% with blocks=self.content %}
    {% for block in blocks %}
        {{ block }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

It shows all the fields of the associated form with this page. I want to access each fields of the associated form individually `(e.g.: field name etc.)` because sometimes I need to add fields before the submit button using javascript. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

To have more control over how the form blocks are rendered, you can easily override the `template` attribute inside `Meta` on your Block.

First, adjust your custom `WagtailFormBlock` class with a template attribute in meta. I renamed the class to `CustomFormBlock` from `MyForm` as this makes it easier to understand this class is a streamfield block, not a form.

```
# file: blocks.py
class CustomFormBlock(WagtailFormBlock):

    class Meta:
        # template variable has been overridden...
        template = 'demo_app/wagtailformblocks/form_block.html'
        app_label = 'demo'
```

Then, create your template in `/templates/demo_app/wagtailformblocks/form_block.html`. You can start by copying and pasting from the default template for this block from the [WagtailFormBlocks codebase](https://github.com/LUKKIEN/wagtailformblocks/blob/master/wagtailformblocks/templates/wagtailformblocks/form_block.html).

```
{% load static %}

<script src="{% static 'wagtailformblocks/js/formhandler.js' %}"></script>

<form action="{{ action_url }}" id="wagtailformblock_{{ form_id }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            <strong>Custom Per Field Content for `{{ field.name }}`</strong>
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

That is all you need to do, now whenever you use the `CustomFormBlock` to link forms to streamfield content it will automatically render using the template you provided.

You can see more documentation on how to render forms in a custom way in Django docs: [working with form templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates).

Notes

- This is a question specific to the [`Wagtail Form Blocks` library](https://wagtailformblocks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).
- WagtailFormBlocks makes a custom StreamBlock available called [WagtailFormBlock](https://github.com/LUKKIEN/wagtailformblocks/blob/master/wagtailformblocks/blocks.py#L33) that gives a selectable dropdown of forms created with the same library.